# What are the alternatives to Java Applet for mobile platform browsers? Is obfuscated Javascript safe?

Tags: java, javascript, mobile, browser, applet

I wrote a Java Applet which encrypts some form fields and then decrypts on the server.  This works fine on desktop computers.  But for tablets and mobile platforms, there's either very limited support or none at all, especially for iOS devices.

Does there exist any alternatives for running code within the mobile device's browser to, in my case, encrypt form fields safely?

I could write an encryption scheme in JavaScript and obfuscate the JavaScript code, but that's a stone throw away from searching how to de-obfuscate JavaScript code.

Anyone got any ideas?

Disclaimer: I am just the messenger.  I am told to write an applet, so I write an applet.  *They* don't want to use SSL and are doing everything they can to avoid it.

Thank you.

Comment: Obfuscation is never a data security measure. And note that Java binary code can be reverse-engineered quite easily as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity What is it that you need to do?

Comment: Encrypting form fields on the client and decrypting on the server? You ever heard of HTTPS/SSL?  What are you guarding against?

Comment: Why have you implemented encryption yourself? Why not just to use HTTPS?

Comment: I should've put in the question that I am just the messenger (I just did).  I was assigned to write an applet, which I did.  They don't want to use SSL, and I have no control over the decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK messenger:

Then it's not the code you need to protect - you need to protect your encryption key, which means using PGP (public Key on client, private key on server).

Not quite as good as two-way SSL, so it depends on your reason for encryption.  You're still more vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

You could always generate a new PGP key pair per session, if you want to start managing this kind of state on your server.

http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will research and implement this solution.  I prefer to use SSL, but, again, it's not my call.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lee Kowalkowski's answer, but I want to add a couple of extra points:

- Assuming that your encryption solution uses public / private key pairs with proper protection of the private keys, then obfuscating the client side code does almost nothing for security
- If your existing Applet based solution is also vulnerable to decompilation, whether or not you obfuscate.  So you need to deploy public / private key encryption there too.
- Rolling your own solution is always risky in the sense that if you make a mistake and build a system that has security flaws, you may not notice it until it is too late; i.e. not using SSL is risky!